# How do I provide access to certain rows that are common for all users when implementing PostgreSQL Row Level Security?

Tags: postgresql, multi-tenant, row-level-security

We have a multi-tenant database and this is a table in which we have implemented row-level security based on tenant_id:

| tenant_id | product_id |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | A |
| 0 | B |
| 1 | 1A |
| 1 | 1B |
| 2 | 2A |
| 2 | 2B |

Our requirement is that the products associated with tenant_id = 0 should be available to all tenants.
Products associated with tenant_id != 0 should only be available to the relevant tenants.

Is there a way to implement this using security definers?
Or do we need to have separate tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can always write multiple conditions while writing RLS policies.
for example: in your case, `create policy *policy_name* on *table_name* for all to public using (tenant_id=current_user or tenant_id = 0)`

Reference: [enter link description here](https://supabase.com/docs/guides/auth/row-level-security#policies-with-security-definer-functions)